# Java Maven Dependency not found (Stanford NLP)

Tags: java, maven, nlp, dependencies

[image]

Hello, i am not sure why i cannot import the stanford nlp library. i did what it said online, put the dependencies in the maven file. I can't find an answer on google hopefully someone can help. its just red and if i hover over it it says dependency not found

Comment: Did you actually try to build this? This looks like IntelliJ or similar. It's quite possible that your maven file is fine, and it's just a matter of your IDE's maven cache being out of date.

Comment: go to the project directory and do :>mvn clean install and try, it might resolve issue.

Comment: Please use text instead of pictures...Check on command line how Maven is trying to download the artifacts ..cause I supose you are trying to access via http instead of https ... https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https (Use a more recent version of Maven)...or you might need to change your settings.xml file...

Comment: @Mayur Thanks that did the trick. Thanks for all your suggestions too. I did a clean then install then maven downloaded the package.

Comment: great @IanLee , keep coding :)